# Android button onClick to display an AlertDialog application crash

Tags: android, fonts, dialog, message, alert

I am trying to display an AlertDialog when I press the Submit button.

```
Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Application1GoodExample.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Your form has been successfully submitted");
                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    textView.setTextSize(40);
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                              dialog.cancel();           
                        } });

                    builder.show();

                }

            });
```

I believe it has something to do with it trying to access `findViewById(android.R.id.message)`

I have defined the TextView in my XML file as follows:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/message" 
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textSize="45sp" 
        android:gravity="center"
        />
```

I just want to change the default AlertDialog message "Your form has been successfully submitted" font size, but my program crashes when I press the Submit button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to access android.R, just remove "android" and it should work (your resources are in com.yourproject.R, not android.R).

```
findViewById(android.R.id.message)
```

Answer (score 1):

First,if you want to set text size for a TextView in XML,the layout in setContentView()in MainActivity must contain a reference to it.
Second, you should replace android.R.id.message by R.id.message.